# How can I find the exact value of this continued fraction?

Tags: continued-fractions

How can I find the value of $$1 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{4 + \cfrac{1}{8 + \cfrac{1}{16 + \cfrac{1}{32 + \cfrac{1}{64 + \ldots}}}}}}}?$$ I have tried approximating the continued fraction and the result is close to $1.6915$. How can I find the exact value of this continued fraction?

Comment: These are called continued fractions not series.

Comment: @Community `\cfrac` should be used for continued fractions, not `\dfrac`.

Comment: Ok @soupless, Thank you, will remember

Comment: See OEIS [A096641](https://oeis.org/A096641), they reference [Ramanujan and the Regular Continued Fraction Expansion of Real Numbers](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0402461).

Comment: Try https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2BN%5BContinuedFractionK%5B2%5En%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+400%7D%5D%2C+1000%5D

Comment: For the fun of it $\frac{1602-542 e+978 e^2 } {1290+247 e+323 e^2 }$ gives 20 exact significant figures